# Passing objects between objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a number of GUI classes that is accessing the same information object which is set from its constructor. 
Each GUI class displays the gui information object in a different way.

Is it better to initialise the object each time in the constructor or just add the object to memory and use it each time a GUI class requires it ? Does either method fall into a design pattern ?

Comment: The second way is probably the singleton pattern. You should try to avoid singleton as much as possible.

Comment: So right now each GUI class creates a new instance of that object in its constructor right? But the information in the object is always the same?

Comment: @Damokles The object is always the same type but some of its member variables will have different values for each GUI class.

Comment: @Thomas Li Why should I avoid the singleton pattern in this case ?

Comment: So the instance is unique to every instance of a GUI, meaning it would not make sense to share it since the member variables will have different values. This rules out the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before even reading up on specific object design patterns, a good starting place is to read up on the MVC (Model View Controller) pattern. It's probably the most commonly used architecture pattern out there, and a google search will bring up tons of good material (Wikipedia would even be a good place to start in this case)

It's used to address the problem you've hinted at, where your various display logic has to frequently access the same information holding logic. In an application which uses an MVC architecture, your code is (more or less) separated into three categories, code which displays information in a UI, code which holds (or models) information, and code which controls the flow of the application and application events. MVC applications commonly use listeners and other event design patterns, like the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [listeners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and [event bus](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/eventbus.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dependency injection, there are a lot of frameworks out there. My favorite is guice but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a strategy pattern?. Basically just define a set of classes that inherit from the same interface such as

```
public interface GUIBehavior {

}
```

//Set of classes

```
public behavior1 implementse GUIBehavior...
```

//In the clases that display the information simply set an attribute for the behavior

```
private GUIBehavior myCurrentBehavior;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't see how this answers original question ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @user470184 Since each GUI is implementing its own behavior you can separate those behaviors into a set of classes. And if at some point you wish to change this behavior at runtime you can simply point the attribute to a new behavior.